# How can i recycle imageView by using imagepath

Tags: android, out-of-memory

Here I am storing all image paths into database. In `TabHost`, If i click FIND tab all images should be displayed. At that time `OutOfMemoryError` is coming. Please help me.
It is very important for me.

```
    Image s = pictures.get(i);
    TableRow imageTableRow = new TableRow(ctx);
    imageTableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(ctx);
    Log.i("NEVERFORGET","PICTURE IMAGE PATH is : " + s.getimagePath());
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(s.getimagePath());
    imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
    imageView.setId(i);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(100,100));
    imageView.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Drawable.createFromPath()` as that is bound to load images at their native resolution. Doubtless these are large images, photos etc, and will therefore require vast amounts of memory once decompressed, and hence your OOM errors. Even if you're then asking them to render into a small box, they are probably fully-sized in memory.

You should instead use [`BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) in conjunction with a suitable choice for [`BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize).

Comment: Any chance you could mark this as the answer then? Thanks! :-)